# Does the servlet specification guarantee single thread initialization and inline attributeChanged events?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have a web application that bootstraps event-receiver from external system when a ServletContext is initialized. All components that need to receive events are listening for ServletContext attribute events and attaching themselves as listeners. As I do not want the event-listeners to miss events, I want to start the event-source only after all listeners have been attached.

I could not find any threading requirements for initialization in the Servlet 2.5 and 3.0 specification, so I was assuming completely async initialization model, yet I noticed that Tomcat fires the ServletContext attribute-changed events immediately from the setAttribute() method. This would mean that if all other servlet containers follow suit, I can simplify my startup procedure.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is an example (I have tried to be as concrete as possible). In my web.xml, I  currently have registered:

- **BootstrapEventSourceContextListener** on servlet-context initialization:

  1. creates event-source and sets it as servlet-context attribute.
  2. the event-source is not started at this time (i.e. it does not emit events)
- **ConsumerAContextAttributeListener** when it receives a notification that the attribute containing the event-source has been set:

  1. looks up the event-source from the servlet-context attribute
  2. instantiates ConsumerA
  3. attaches ConsumerA to the event-source
  4. sets the data model of ConsumerA as attribute in the servlet-context
- **ConsumerBContextAttributeListener** - same as Comsumer A
- **ConsumerCContextAttributeListener** - same as A and B, except that it also depends on the datamodel of B
- **StartEventSourceFilter** when a page is accessed:

  1. looks up the event-source from the servlet-context
  2. starts the event-source
  3. blocks until the event-source has received initial snapshot
  4. continues to render the page

The question is whether I really need the StartEventSourceFilter, or is it guaranteed that all the consumers will be attached the moment I set the event-source attribute (i.e. attribute listeners are not deferred). I care about Tomcat, Jetty and Websphere.

Comment: I am confused due to all the ambiguity in the question. Please provide some concrete code. For example, you told to use a `Filter` for the job, but the "on context init" is normally to be done by a `ServletContextListener`. Also there is no such method as `attributeChanged()` in the entire servlet API. There's however an `attributeReplaced()` in `ServletContextAttributeListener`.

Comment: Unfortunately the servlet API is quite verbose, so I am trying to describe what I am doing rather than using actual code (which I have to anonymize, so it is a pain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody answered, I dug in and here is what I found:

The Servlet 3.0 spec does not mention whether listeners are notified inline or asynchronously, but it provides the following guarantees in chapter 11:

- 11.2 All listeners, eligible to handle a particular event are invoked in the order they are registered in web.xml
- 11.5 ServletContext lifecycle listeners will be instantiated before the container serving its first request. There is no explicit threading specification, but given that the point above guarantees the ordering, I assume this means that they will also be invoked sequentially and synchronously (wait for the current instance to finish before callinfg the next) - most likely this means same thread. Also not explicitly stated, but I find it reasonable to assume that the container would wait until all notification methods complete before servicing the first request. Confirmed that is what Tomcat and Jetty do.
- 11.5 Attribute changes to ServletContext and HTTP session can run concurently. Given that this also mentions HTTP session, I take this to mean that if servlets modify the context, these modifications can run concurrently. In our case, the context listeners modify context attributes, and as in previous point we have stated they are running synchronously, and as the ordering requirement holds for ctx-attribute listeners, we can assume that attribute listeners at init time run sequentially.

The only remaining issue is whether the servlet-context attribute listeners always run inline with the setters, or are there implementations that queue them up (say to coalesce multiple change events for the same attribute). I believe it is reasonable to assume that the intent of the spec and all implementations would notify the listeners inline (and confirmed this for Tomcat and Jetty).

Bottom-line is: when setting a context attribute from a context-init listener, it is reasonably safe to assume that all context-attribute listeners will have finished when the setter method returns. The specification does not explicitly guarantee this, but all specified constraints and guarantees point in that direction.